# How exactly the channel assignment works in Golang?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

In following code, the value recieved from `ch` channel is `4` when we have added `b = a` after every go routine call.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    a := ch
    b := ch

    a = make(chan int)
    go f(a, b)
    b = a

    a = make(chan int)
    go f(a, b)
    b = a

    a = make(chan int)
    go f(a, b)
    b = a

    go func() { a <- 1 }()
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}

func f(a, b chan int) {
    b <- 1 + <-a
}
```

On the other hand, In following code, the value recieved from `ch` channel is `2` when we have removed `b = a` after every go routine call.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    a := ch
    b := ch

    a = make(chan int)
    go f(a, b)

    a = make(chan int)
    go f(a, b)

    a = make(chan int)
    go f(a, b)

    go func() { a <- 1 }()
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}

func f(a, b chan int) {
    b <- 1 + <-a
}
```

Can someone explain why this is happening, also I wonder how exactly `b = a` behaving here.

As per my expectation, in both cases above, the behaviour should be same, the value from `ch` channel should come as `2`.

Comment: Run your code under the race detector.

Comment: @Volker its running as usual and showing the output only with race detector without showing any data race traces.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you're creating [what in Go is called a "pipeline"](https://go.dev/blog/pipelines).  Every  goroutine gets a unique set of output and input channels.  The input of each goroutine is the output of the previous goroutine.  Thus, each goroutine must actually execute for `<-ch` to return a value.

In the second case, all goroutines share `b` aka `ch`.  As soon as one goroutine executes, `<-ch` is available for reading.  Due to the behavior of the goroutine scheduler, this behavior appears to be consistent, but that's really just happenstance.

Comment: I agree that we should actually return data from each go routine using `<-ch`. But, I observed in [Go Pipeline](https://go.dev/blog/pipelines), we are no where assigning one channel to another channel like `b = a`, rather we are putting the underlying channel value to another channel like `b <- a` Thats the thing I want to understand here, how exactly channel assignment is working(in above example particularly), as per my understanding, `b = a` simply will copy the reference value of `a` to `b`. But not sure how values are flowing :)

Comment: "I observed in Go Pipeline ... we are putting the underlying channel value to another channel like `b <- a`" That's not happening in [the link you included](https://go.dev/blog/pipelines).  Nothing on that page creates a channel on which you can send a channel.  You *can* do that, but it's not done on the page you reference.

Comment: oh yeah @erik258, what I meant to say is like putting the value of one channel to another, probably its syntax is `b <- <-a` or we can say taking value from channel `a` in a variable and pushing that onto channel `b` like first `x <- a` then `b <- x`.

My main question here is how channel assignment is working in above example i.e., `b = a`.

This example which I created is actually taken from [Daisy-chain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs) at 27:47.

I have posted the simpler version here. Indeed that is an example of a pipeline, but I wonder how :)

Comment: Let me make it more simpler,
`b <- <- a`: I understand, its a pipeline mechanism, but `b = a`:  I wonder how it is behaving like a pipeline.